# How do I set a session array variable in laravel if it doesn't already exist?

Tags: php, laravel

In my blade file, I have:

```
<p>{{ session()->push('user.rooms', $room->room_id) }}</p>
<p>{{ var_dump(Session::get("user.rooms")) }}</p>
```

This outputs:

```
array(6) {[0]=>string(1) "1"[1]=>int(1)[2]=>int(1)[3]=>int(1)[4]=>int(1)[5]=>int(1) }
```

How can I check to see if the value "1" already exists in the user.rooms array, and if not, then set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
@if (empty(session()->get('user.rooms')) || ! in_array($room->room_id, session()->get('user.rooms')) )
    <p>{{ session()->push('user.rooms', $room->room_id) }}</p>
@endif;
```

But i could not understand why are you setting session value in view. Better you do it in controller and the same code will work in controller too

Comment: I tried it, but when I refresh the page, its adding a 1 to the array:  array(24) {[0]=>string(1) "1"[1]=>int(1)[2]=>int(1)[3]=>int(1)[4]=>int(1)[5]=>int(1)[6]=>int(1)[7]=>int(1)[8]=>int(1)[9]=>int(1)[10]=>int(1)[11]=>int(1)[12]=>int(1)[13]=>int(1)[14]=>int(1)[15]=>int(1)[16]=>int(1)[17]=>int(1)[18]=>int(1)[19]=>int(1)[20]=>int(1)[21]=>int(1)[22]=>int(1)[23]=>int(1) }

Comment: try changing `isset` with `empty`. updated answer check it

Comment: Answer worked in view, moved code to controller based on suggestion, and verified it worked there too.  Code in controller:  if (empty(session()->get('user.rooms')) || ! in_array($room->room_id, session()->get('user.rooms')) )
    session()->push('user.rooms', $room->room_id);